# How do I perform an action in response to an item being added to an NSArrayController's content?

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller, first-responder

I have an `NSArrayController` whose content is the "`servers`" property of my AppDelegate.

I have an `NSTextField` which is bound to the "`selection.name`" property of the `NSArrayController` and I have buttons attached to the "`add:`" and "`remove:`" actions on the `NSArrayController`.

What I'd like to see happen, is when I click the "Add" button, the `NSTextField` becomes the first responder so that users can immediately edit the name of the server.

My current strategy is to observe the "`arrangedObjects`" property of the `NSArrayController` but all I get back from the `NSKeyValueChangeKindKey` is the `NSKeyValueChangeSetting` enum. I was hoping to get the `NSKeyValueChangeInsertion` value so I could ask the text field to become the First Responder.

My question is, am I going about this the right way or is there a more common way to accomplish this? I'm doing fine hooking up bindings, I'm just struggling with how to insert my own behavior in the cracks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subclass of NSArrayController with an outlet to the text field. Override the `add:` method; in your implementation, immediately send the message up to `super`, then tell the window to make the text field the first responder.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For some reason, I had to send the makeFirstResponder: message with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: (after calling super) to make it take.

Comment: You probably need the delay since -[NSArrayController add:] internally delays its work.